# Linux Mint workspace switch time

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, workspaces

I use Cinnamon workspace switcher. Everything is okay, but the visual effect is too fast.

Is it possible to set the duration of workspace switching effect?

Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: I can't test since I don't use cinnamon but mate. But try to give a look in `CompizConfig Settings Manager`, under `effects > animations`

Comment: there is no compiz in operation system.

Comment: Since nobody provide any answer at this time, I have posted one. Although, you may be disappointed to find that it does not work as expected.

Comment: Effects - Enable Window effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated: Yes and no.

Yes, it is possible by configuring certain variable that is found in the source code of Cinnamon workspace switcher. No, because it does not work as expected.

### Switching time is hardcoded

The only clue about the workspace switching time was found at GitHub repository, where source codes for Cinnamon is maintained. [This comment from a contributor](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1037#issuecomment-28988957) in late 2013 was the clue.

> [...] there's a hardcoded .25 second animation for switching workspaces when effects are enabled.

Now we know that the animation is hardcoded, but there was no indication on which part of the source code the comment actually meant. However, searching within the repostitory include result of [this location in the source code directory](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/tree/master/js/ui).

The directory path is `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/` for Cinnamon in Linux Mint that has been installed on local machine. There are two files that seemed relevant in the directory.

1. `workspace.js` with the line `const FOCUS_ANIMATION_TIME = 0.15;`
2. `workspacesView.js` with the line `const WORKSPACE_SWITCH_TIME = 0.25;`

By comparing with ".25 second" comment, the relevant file is most likely `workspacesView.js` that is tally with `0.25` value used in the file. The other line with `0.15` has since been removed at all.

### Manual configuration in Cinnamon

Cinnamon is based on GTK+ 3, which is similar to how GNOME 3 works. This means, some source codes are written in JavaScript. Cinnamon workspace switcher is one of them. Source code written in JavaScript requires no compilation to run, so any changes made could be applied immediately.

The four simple steps to make changes:

1. Open the JavaScript file in a text editor with root or sudo permission.
2. Change the constant value to a larger value for slower animation, vice versa.
3. Save the file.
4. Restart Cinnamon (Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and press <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Finally, user can test and observe the changes made to the animation.

### Does not work as expected

**Workspace switching time**: The JavaScript file is `workspacesView.js` and the constant value is changed from `0.25` to `3.25` or any value of choice. But that does not seem to work: I observed no difference, regardless of using the shortcut keys or using the workspace switcher applet.

I have a proof that worked for me, which is to change the animation duration for toggle scale that has keyboard shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> keys.

```
// Time for initial animation going into Overview mode
const ANIMATION_TIME = 0.25;
```

**Toggle scale time**: The JavaScript file is `overview.js` and the constant value is changed from `0.25` to `3.25` similarly. This time, the four simple steps will result in successful, longer animation of toggle scale. At 3.25 seconds, I observed the result in a slow motion.

If the changes made were successful, then one would certainly notice.

**Disclaimer**: This answer assumes that user has enabled the desktop effects in Cinnamon. Go to **System Settings > Appearance - Effects**. Look for "Enable effects" or similar option and make sure it is ON or checked.

If the instructions didn't work, that means either the schema is deprecated, or other dependencies are preventing the changes from being applied. Someone else may have a better answer.

Tested with Cinnamon 2.2 in Linux Mint 17 (Qiana), and Cinnamon 3.8 in Linux Mint Debian Edition 3 (Cindy). Does not work as expected, yet.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have changed this constant, but it does not work. I hope developers will fix it in future releases.

Answer (score 12):

I think the animation of switch workspace is annoying.So, in Cinnamon 3.0.7, I backup

***/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/windowManager.js***

and edit

`const WINDOW_ANIMATION_TIME = 0.25;`

to

`const WINDOW_ANIMATION_TIME = 0;`

then restart cinnamon by ***Alt+F2***, input ***r*** and ***Enter***

And you can set bigger number to make animation slower.

Comment: This isn't exactly what the OP asked for, but it was very helpful for me since I also found the animation too slow (on my 2018 discrete GPU, sad...). Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found myself trying to fix the same issue.

The other comments on this post have been helpful, however it seems the constant which affects workspace transition times has been moved.

Currently the value which is relevant to change in **/usr/share/cinnamon/js/ui/windowManager.js** is called `WORKSPACE_ANIMATION_TIME` For me this resides on line 226 of the aforementioned file.

There also seems to be a `WORKSPACE_OSD_TIMEOUT` near the top of the file, which has to do with the displayed time of the "Workspace X" Message when you switch workspaces.

Setting `const WORKSPACE_OSD_TIMEOUT = 0.05` along with `WORKSPACE_ANIMATION_TIME = 0` gave me the experience I was looking for.

Hope this helps someone else out!